# Node - Mongo DB - How do I query for a specific nested field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

In short: I setup up session authentication for my node-express app with mongodb. If a user has already a valid session entity in the db a new session should NOT be created. Now I want to make a query for the specific user-id in my session collection.

### Collection

The collection looks like follows:

```
{"_id":"HbAE-qMXPWl7C8tDUnC****q8OoEf76vN","expires":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1576133617190"}},"session":"{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":86399999,\"expires\":\"2019-12-12T06:36:29.898Z\",\"secure\":false,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\",\"sameSite\":true},\"user\":{\"uid\":\"5df08a1b8a60c174840d2986\"}}"}
```

And my query looks like this:

```
public async compareSessionIds(uid: string, sid: string) {
    //uid is: 5df08a1b8a60c174840d2986 ==> the same as in the entity
    const user: User | null = await this.connectionManager.db('users').collection<User>('sessions').findOne({uid: uid} as any);
    console.log('user found: ', user); // user found:  null
    return user && user._id === sid;
}
```

But my query returns everytime `null` so I am assuming my query is wrong. How do I query correctly for a specific nested field in mongodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be like this:

```
.findOne({"session.user.uid": uid});
```

Because, `uid` is in `session.user`! Hope it helps.